# PHP script keeps sending Email evertime the page is loaded

Tags: php, html, email

I have put together a simple contact form for my website. Using PHP to POST the data and send directly to my email address. But for some reason every time I visit the page on my website. I still get the test message Displaying under the Form. Then when I reload the website and visit the link again it still displays the thank you message. and automatically sends an email. Im still in testing mode 2 days before my launch and I need this figure out. Considering I am novice to php I dont know what goes where....  check out my website to get a live view https://trillumonopoly.com  (click "Contact Us" link in menu) I would like for the contact form to disappear and echo the thank you message once sent. And reset after the page is reloaded. I am also using Jquery ajax to load all my pages into a div container. So I would like to keep the content inside that div without forwarding to the Echo message page, leaving my index page

Heres My ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadMainContent('main');

    $('body').delegate('.navMenu', 'click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadMainContent($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});

function loadMainContent(page) {
    $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
}
```

here is html for the form:

```
<div class="general row container-fluid"><br>
    <center><img src="img/divider.png" class="img-fluid"></center>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" height="540px" width="540px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 container"><center>
            <br><h1 class="form-title">Contact Us</h1><br></center>
            <div class="container"> 
                <form action="pages/mail.php" method="GET" class="box2">
                    NAME:
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="YOUR NAME HERE" required>
                    <br><br>
                    EMAIL:
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL HERE" required>
                    <br><br>
                    MESSAGE:<br>
                    <textarea name="message" rows=10 cols=23 placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE HERE" required></textarea>
                    <br><Br>
                    <button type="submit" value="Message Sent" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="background-color:"red">SUBMIT</button
                </form>
                <center><?php include('mail.php'); ?></center>
           </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Here is My simple PHP:

```
<?php 

$name = $POST['name'];
$email = $POST['email'];
$message = $POST['message'];

mail("info@trillumonopoly.com","ILLUMONOPOLY WEB Contact", $message,"From: $email\r\n");

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us!";




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than check everything before send mail.

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
    $name = $POST['name'];
    $email = $POST['email'];
    $message = $POST['message'];

    mail("info@trillumonopoly.com","ILLUMONOPOLY WEB Contact", $message,"From: $email\r\n");

    echo "Thank You For Contacting Us!";
}
```

And send POST request to the index, not mail.php.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    ...
```

So the user can see your message at the end of contact form.

Comment: This Works so it doesnt keep sendng emails but It doesnt open in my selected div and it takes the user away from my main page. Thats what I am trying to avoid

Comment: It also doesnt display the message

Comment: Oh I see, you should send POST request to current page URL or empty form action (Edited my answer so you can understand it clearly). So when you include mail.php at the end of form, it will show the message.

Comment: Are You saying leave the form action blank (form action="")???  becuase I tried that and It doesnt work. It redirects me to the index page and no email is sent... Do I include the mail php form via php in my index header?

Comment: Now I Get no email? and In the emails there is no message just to and from details... no message